# Multiple checkboxes in dropdown list for multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column K that is headed with "Downloads". I want to be able to click a cell in column K, then a listbox with checkboxes appears and I select from a list of 7 (which is stored in another sheet) the names of the files that have been downloaded by that user. These are then added to the cell, separated by commas.

The issue I'm having is that each cell in column K needs to be different, so for example, if my list of downloads is "Item A, Item B, Item C" etc. and then in K3 I check Item A, then it should display just Item A. However, then if I click K29 and select Item A, B and C, then it should display "Item A, Item B, Item C" in that cell.

Here's an example of something I was testing which didn't work as it filled EVERY cell in column K with what I checked. Also, the dropdown was always visible and I only want it visible when a cell is clicked:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Dim lngCurrentItem As Long
Dim strCurrentItem As String
Dim strAllSelectedItems As String
Dim rngOutput As Range

Set rngOutput = [K1:K999]

strAllSelectedItems = ""

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    strCurrentItem = ListBox1.List(i)

If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
    If strAllSelectedItems = "" Then
        strAllSelectedItems = strCurrentItem
    Else
        strAllSelectedItems = strAllSelectedItems & " - " & strCurrentItem
    End If
End If

Next i

If strAllSelectedItems = "" Then
rngOutput = "No Items Selected"
ElseIf InStr(1, strAllSelectedItems, " - ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
rngOutput = strAllSelectedItems & " Are Selected"
Else
    rngOutput = strAllSelectedItems & " Is Selected"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please can you post the code you are currently using?

Comment: Added to original post

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use a `Userform` if I were doing this.

You can insert one in your editor and make it look like this:

[image]

I've added a `Label` and changed its properties as follows:

- Name = lblPrompt
- Autosize = true
- Wordwrap = false

I've added a `Listbox` and changed its properties as follows:

- Name = lboxItems
- MultiSelect = 1 - fmMultiSelectMulti
- ListStyle = 1 - fmListStyleOption
- List item = Sheet2!A1:A7 ~> use the range of your own items.

I've added 2 `CommandButtons` and named them btnOk and btnCanx (and changed their captions to 'OK' and 'Cancel'.

Then in the code for the Userform, I've used:

```
Option Explicit
Private mCell As Range
Public Sub PopUp(user As String, cell As Range)
    Dim i As Integer

    Set mCell = cell
    lblPrompt = "Downloads by " & user
    For i = 0 To lboxItems.ListCount - 1
        lboxItems.Selected(i) = False
    Next
    Me.Show
End Sub

Private Sub btnCanx_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub btnOk_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim itemText As String

    For i = 0 To lboxItems.ListCount - 1
        If lboxItems.Selected(i) Then
            If Len(itemText) > 0 Then
                itemText = itemText & ", "
            End If
            itemText = itemText & lboxItems.List(i)
        End If
    Next

    mCell.Value = itemText

    Me.Hide

End Sub
```

And, finally, on the `Worksheet` code behind. I've put:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim user As String

    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(cell, Columns("K")) Is Nothing Then
            user = CStr(cell.Offset(, -10).Value2)
            UserForm1.PopUp user, cell
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```